# How can I resolve linker issues when I compile this C++ program that requires GLUT?

Tags: c++, opengl, linker, compiler-errors, glut

I'm trying to compile this C++ program which utilizes the GLUT32 libraries.

Right now I'm getting the following errors:

> Error 1   error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol
>   _gluPerspective@32    Camera.obj  soundCube
>   Error 2   error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol
>   _gluLookAt@72 Camera.obj  soundCube Error 3   error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol
>   __imp__glMaterialfv@12    GLWindow.obj    soundCube
>   Error 4   error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol
>   __imp__glClear@4  GLWindow.obj    soundCube Error 5   error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol
>   __imp__glClearColor@16    GLWindow.obj    soundCube
>   Error 6   error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol
>   __imp__glMaterialf@12 GLWindow.obj    soundCube Error 7   error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol
>   __imp__glEnd@0    GLWindow.obj    soundCube Error 8   error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol
>   __imp__glRasterPos2f@8    GLWindow.obj    soundCube
>   Error 9   error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol
>   __imp__timeGetTime@0  GLWindow.obj    soundCube Error 10  error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol
>   __imp__glDisable@4    GLWindow.obj    soundCube
>   Error 11  error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol
>   __imp__glBegin@4  GLWindow.obj    soundCube Error 12  error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol
>   __imp__glColor4f@16   GLWindow.obj    soundCube
>   Error 13  error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol
>   __imp__glPopMatrix@0  GLWindow.obj    soundCube Error 14  error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol
>   __imp__glPushMatrix@0 GLWindow.obj    soundCube Error 15  error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol
>   __imp__glRotatef@16   GLWindow.obj    soundCube
>   Error 16  error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol __imp__glBlendFunc@8
>
> ...
>
> Error 56  fatal error LNK1120: 55
>   unresolved
>   externals C:\Users\Simucal\Documents\Downloads\SoundCubeSrc   soundCube

I'm not that experienced in C++ but I've tried to set up GLUT correctly so this project can link against it.

I downloaded the GLUT32 library for [Nate Robin's page](http://www.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html).

I then placed the following files in:

- glut.h - C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include\gl
- glut32.lib - C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib
- glut.dll - C:\Windows\System32

I also selected the Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Additional Dependencies -> Added "glut32.lib"

If anyone wants to see what project I'm working with, it is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/638285/SoundCubeSrc.zip).

What step am I missing or doing wrong in order to resolve these errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unresolved symbols are from the GL and GLU libraries. You need to add the link libraries for them as well.

Answer (score 1):

it looks to me like you're mixing static and dynamic link options.  I'm downloading your project to investigate, but what type of compilation are you doing?

I didn't see a reference to the glut .lib file in the project...

I added the library reference and LIB/INCLUDE paths:

```
diff --git a/soundCube/soundCube.vcproj b/soundCube/soundCube.vcproj
index 62e04c1..b71eb20 100644
--- a/soundCube/soundCube.vcproj
+++ b/soundCube/soundCube.vcproj
@@ -41,6 +41,7 @@
            <Tool
                Name="VCCLCompilerTool"
                Optimization="0"
+               AdditionalIncludeDirectories="d:\temp\glut"
                PreprocessorDefinitions="WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE"
                MinimalRebuild="true"
                BasicRuntimeChecks="3"
@@ -60,7 +61,9 @@
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCLinkerTool"
+               AdditionalDependencies="glut32.lib"
                LinkIncremental="2"
+               AdditionalLibraryDirectories="d:\temp\glut\GL"
                GenerateDebugInformation="true"
                SubSystem="1"
                TargetMachine="1"
@@ -114,6 +117,7 @@
                Name="VCCLCompilerTool"
                Optimization="2"
                EnableIntrinsicFunctions="true"
+               AdditionalIncludeDirectories="d:\temp\glut"
                PreprocessorDefinitions="WIN32;NDEBUG;_CONSOLE"
                RuntimeLibrary="0"
                EnableFunctionLevelLinking="true"
@@ -132,7 +136,9 @@
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCLinkerTool"
+               AdditionalDependencies="glut32.lib"
                LinkIncremental="1"
+               AdditionalLibraryDirectories="d:\temp\glut\GL"
                GenerateDebugInformation="true"
                SubSystem="1"
                OptimizeReferences="2"
```

Comment: I'm working on a project handed down from a Japanese student who is no longer at the University.  This is his portion of it.  I'm not entirely sure.  If you see anything that could be of use when you look at the project I would appreciate it!